# Decoding a JSON file into different target arrays

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I have got my code to decode a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "WIW-919",
    "factionGroupName" : "CommonWealth",
    "characters" : [
      {
        "id" : "NPJ-160",
        "name" : "Agatha Tavernfrau",
        "faction" : "CommonWealth",
        "mugShot" : "AgathaMugShot",
        "standeeImage" : "AgathaStandee",
        "cardBackImage" : "AgathaSignaturev1",
        "cardFrontImage" : "AgathaFrontv1",
        "keywords" : [
          "Human"
        ]
      },  
  {
    "id" : "PAQ-610",
    "factionGroupName" : "Dominion",
    "characters" : [
      {
        "id" : "JKA-020",
        "name" : "Doug the flatulent",
        "faction" : "Dominion",
        "mugShot" : "DougMugShot",
        "standeeImage" : "DougStandee",
        "cardBackImage" : "DougSignaturev2",
        "cardFrontImage" : "DougFrontv2",
        "keywords" : [
          "Animal",
          "Goblin"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In essence I have two top level structs using factionGroupName, which then in turn use another struct to decode the characters objects.

I am able to read in the full JSON file and foreach loop round the contents and output them in a list etc.

However - what I really want to do is decode the JSON file and place the top level array into two different structs - so IF factionGroupName equals CommonWealth, then use a struct called commonwealth, but if factionGroupName equals Dominion use a different struct.

Can i do this? Or do i need to use different JSON files?

I am struggling to read on how i can use the custom decoder rules, but i think i just want to do a value test on the factionGroupName variable and change the struct it then calls?

---

This is the current code to read in the Json:

```
import SwiftUI
struct markTestName: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var factionGroupName: String
    var characters: [charDetail]
}
struct charDetail: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var faction: String
    var mugShot : String
    var standeeImage : String
    var cardBackImage : String
    var cardFrontImage : String
    var keywords: [String]
}
```

Comment: The question I have is: are you going to have more faction groups in the future? With the approach you're trying to take, scalability will be challenging if you're making a variable for each group. Why not figure out a way to leverage comparisons so you can make code more generic.

Comment: There could be more Factions, but maybe only 3 or 4.

Comment: Is there a difference between the properties of the the `characters` array?  There doesn't seem to be.  Wouldn't it be easier just to load the data from the JSON and then simply split it into different arrays or a dictionary keyed by faction or something like that?

Comment: I would still want to be able to read in the JSON data and say click on a commonwealth button, and then a list of only characters that are associated with commonwealth be displayed - or have a full list and the option to hide items if they are not aligned etc etc.

Comment: @Paulw11 - yes that is kinda what i want to do, but i'm not sure how to do that , a character could be aligned to multiple factions though.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a dictionary of `[String:[Character]]` is what you want.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think that's the best course of action if the ID of the faction group is unimportant, so that would work great if the ID of the faction group is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating a couple of `Codable` structs to hold your JSON data:

```
struct Faction: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let characters: [Character]
}

struct Character: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let faction: String
    let mugShot: String
    let standeeImage: String
    let cardBackImage: String
    let cardFrontImage: String
    let keywords: [String]
}
```

Then create a struct to hold your factions (and any other data you might need)

```
struct GameData {
    let factions:[Faction]

    var factionNames:[String] {
        get {
            return Array(Set(factions.compactMap({ $0.name })))
        }
    }

    func faction(named: String) -> Faction? {
        return factions.first { (faction) -> Bool in
            faction.name == named
        }
    }     
}
```

If `factions` is the `[Faction]` array you get from your JSON, you would create an instance of `GameData` using

```
let gameData = GameData(factions: factions)
```

Now, you can get a particular faction using:

```
if let commonwealth = gameData.faction(named:"Commonwealth") {
   // Do something
} else {
   // Faction not found
}
```

Since you have a relatively small number of factions, simply using `first(where:)` to search the array isn't a big performance problem, particularly as you probably only do this once and save the faction in another variable.

You can also get a list of all factions (to dynamically create elements such as your faction filtering buttons) using `gameData.factionNames`

Comment: I will try and follow what this is all trying to do. How would I generate a List using that gameData.factionNames? or even view the contents? thanks.

Comment: Well, `gameData.factionNames` is an array of strings; you can iterate over that, calling `faction(named:)` for each element in the array and then loop over the `characters` array for each faction. You could also use the arrays to provide data for a tableview.

Comment: please assume I am silly. I do not know any basic Swift (I know I should learn before posting on here!!) - Can I just use a normal foreach(gameData.factionNames?

Comment: Yes...it depends on how you want to display the data. Whether you are using SwiftUI list or a UIKit tableview...

Comment: using SwiftUI - just want to output the factionnames from out of the array into a list to display on scree - so I can see that the contents are correct - ie contain the factions in my json data :)

Comment: Did this
foreach(gameData.factionNames, id: \self)

Comment: Can you replace .factionNames - with a Variable X of type String = "factionNames".
and then run gameData."X" - but it still interprets that as gameData.factionNames?

Comment: To list all characters from all factions you need two nested `forEach` loops; one to loop over the factions and the inner one to loop over the characters for the faction.